# Gltf 2.0 Not exporting animations

Tags: animation, export, gltf

I made a simple subdivided cube with a simple armature and a simple animation, for testing the Glb/Gltf exporter.

No matter all exporting options I tried, the model gets correctly exported, with materials, vertex groups, armature, but no animation data.

I've tried with NLA, with actions in action editor, with all 3 different file format (Glb, Gltf, Gltf Embedded), checking and unchecking all different export options.

I've tried without filters, filtering by collections, filtering by selected.

I've always obtained everything correctly exported except animations, even reimporting into a .blend file or a gltf viewer (in the data analisys I get "animationCount": 0, in the importing .blend file no action is present).

I've read all the official documentation, but couldn't find any info to solve the problem.

What am I missing?

Windows 10, blender 3.3.1 and 3.4.0, i7 8 threads, 32 Gb Ram, Gtx 970.

Thank you.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: i just exported gltf, and imported again - > worked. But i am on macos and tried it on 3.5 alpha

Comment: Thanks Chris, it's something very strange, I can't find a solution.

Comment: Do you by any chance have Auto-Rig Pro installed? Try disabling it from your preferences and trying to export again.

Comment: I had the exact same issue, which was solved after disabling the Auto-Rig Pro add-on. Thanks for the tip! @molevision